# What method is used to create a multiple curved line with Sprite Kit using swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm in the process of creating a game using sprite kit and swift - the question I have is... Is there any way to create the "RED" line shown in the attached image by setting points - Instead of flat ground I'm looking for more of a "Tiny Wings" style wave.

Attached image shows blue blocks falling with gravity and resting in the low points of the line.

I just want to draw the RED line using Sprite Kit and swift where the line could be as long as I set it for.

Thank you in advance for the help or ideas

SOF won't let me attach image - here's a link:
Img Link: https://sites.google.com/site/imagestoreage428/home/red-line.png

Comment: did you try using a CGPathRef?

Comment: CGPath works great for a point to point line, but I'm looking for more of a way to set multiple points - Something along the lines of a CGPathCreateMutable() with an array of points that I can keep adding to the array to extend the line. But between the points the line would have to arc up, then down, etc and depending on the distance between the points it would determine the radius of the arc. Still new to Swift.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by point to point line; I've countlessly used the `CGPathAddArc`, `CGPathAddRelativeArc`, `CGPathAddArcToPoint`, `CGPathAddCurveToPoint` methods to create arcs in my games. If you need to add points later, just make the `CGPathRef` a `CGMutablePathRef`.